# Implementing auth in web application

Tags: java, configuration, oauth, openid

I want to use auth application for my web application to skip the registration process for user . I am using http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/ java library for implementation of auth.I am facing following problem

1.I have created the secret key with those auth provider like twitter. but i am having problem while running this app locally on my system as i give the address of my site required while generating the secret key.

2.I am not able to configure my host file so that it take the properties my the address which i gave while generating the secret key .

Here is the piece of code executing .

```
package com.auth.actions;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils;
import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProvider;
import org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProviderFactory;

import com.auth.form.AuthForm;

public class SocialAuthenticationAction extends Action {

        final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(SocialAuthenticationAction.class);

        @Override
        public ActionForward execute(final ActionMapping mapping,
                        final ActionForm form, final HttpServletRequest request,
                        final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

                AuthForm authForm = (AuthForm) form;
                String id = authForm.getId();
                System.out.println("in authentieavtaonsdfsaf");
                AuthProvider provider = AuthProviderFactory.getInstance(id);
                String returnToUrl = RequestUtils.absoluteURL(request,"/socialAuthSuccessAction.do").toString();
                authForm.setProvider(provider);
                String url = provider.getLoginRedirectURL(returnToUrl);
                LOG.info("Redirecting to: " + url);
                if (url != null) {
                        ActionForward fwd = new ActionForward("openAuthUrl", url, true);
                        return fwd;
                }
                return mapping.findForward("failure");
        }
}
```

Here at line number 23 it is thowing null pointer exception saying that provider is coming as null

ERROR MSG::

> Jan 23, 2011 12:26:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet action threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.Properties.load(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.brickred.socialauth.AuthProviderFactory.getInstance(AuthProviderFactory.java:72)
>     at
>   com.auth.actions.SocialAuthenticationAction.execute(SocialAuthenticationAction.java:31)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthProvider provider = AuthProviderFactory.getInstance(id);` is throwing a NPE, because a property-file should be loaded, which does not exist:
`java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)`

But I don't know, which one is missing. I am sure you have to include some kind of property-file.

**edit**
http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/StrutsSample
In this sample-project you ca see a file called oauth_consumer.properties 
May be that property-file is missing?

Comment: @ckuethbach I am trying to run this app locally but i am having problem while configure .While generating the key for oauth from twitter i gave the return url as address of  website  eg: www.xyz.com .So twitter is returning response at that address but i want run that at localhost .I allready modify my host file to point localhost to www.xyz.com .But still getting the same problem .

Comment: Thanxs .Now I able to find out the property file missing .But now I am facing one more problem this thing is working fine on my localhost but when I am trying to run on my server its showing error page .