# Running web application on local host

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat, oauth, twitter-oauth

I wrote a web-application which is using java library SOCIAL AUTH for oauth .
For this i need to generate a secret with oauth provider like google,twitter .

while generating the key i gave the location of  site eg: www.xyz.com .
Now these oauth provider are retuning their response at the location www.xyz.com

But i want to test my application on localhost wheather is going fine or not.So while runnning on localhost oauth provider is coming as null .

IS there any way by which i can use do by which i can say my tomcat to take the properties or response from www.xyz.com  .So that it ll be able to read the response coming from oauth provider

Comment: I am not sure about it. But try giving your external IP:<port> instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1):

One trick for these types of situations is to temporarily change your /etc/hosts file (if you're on Linux or Mac) so that www.xyz.com points to your localhost.  That is, put the following line in the file:

```
127.0.0.1    www.xyz.com
```

Then, when the remote site redirects you back to www.xyz.com, that will resolve to localhost.  You just have to remember to comment out this line in /etc/hosts whenever you want to access the real production system.

(You can do the same thing on Windows, but I can't remember where the equivalent of /etc/hosts is on Windows, and I don't have access to a Windows box right now.)

Comment: I have allready changed my host file as u said but still getting the same error but not abe to figure this out ...

Comment: can u plz look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770084/implementing-auth-in-web-application